# QLPreviewController does not show some PDF files (it says "Loading" forever)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, pdf, qlpreviewcontroller

I use `QLPreviewController` is very simple way: I have `NSMutableArray<NSURL*> *_files;`

I launch it

```
QLPreviewController* ql = [QLPreviewController new];
ql.dataSource = self;
ql.delegate = self;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:ql animated:TRUE ];
```

And I provide files

```
 -(NSInteger)numberOfPreviewItemsInPreviewController:(QLPreviewController *)controller {
    return _files.count;
}

-(id <QLPreviewItem>)previewController:(QLPreviewController *)controller previewItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    return _files[index];
}
```

It works for any doc, docx, xls, xlsx, and some PDFs. But several PDF are not displayed! It simply shows "Loading" and nothing more. I click on "share" button, choose "copy to actobat reader" and it opens in AR perfectly!

No errors in logs. What can I do?

Comment: Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com and attach the files that cannot be previewed.

Comment: @ThomasDeniau , number of my bug is ``26917759``. Please, take a look

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it does not work if you have ./ in path. It works for docx, but not for pdf.
Following url works:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"./ok" withExtension:@"docx"];
```

Following works as well

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"file" withExtension:@"pdf"];
```

But this DOES NOT

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"./file" withExtension:@"pdf"];
```